# Fully faithful functor from schemes to spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, schemes

Is there a fully faithful functor from the category of schemes 
to the category of topological spaces and continuous maps (or some other sufficiently topological objects, e.g. smooth manifolds and diffeomorphisms or metric spaces and continuous maps)? At least a faithful functor? We do not require the functor to interact well with the forgetful functor.

What if take a field $k$ with no non-trivial automorphisms and restrict to $k$-schemes and $k$-morphisms?

Comment: If there exists/does not exists such a functor, what is the next thing you are interested to in?

Comment: The category of schemes has a faithful functor to the category of sets (see https://mathoverflow.net/a/160768) and therefore also a faithful functor to topological spaces.

Comment: There's some related work by Trnkova, Pultr, and others -- keyword "universal categories". According to the introduction of [Universal concrete categories and functors](https://eudml.org/doc/91527), every concrete category fully embeds into the category of topological spaces and _open_ maps; this is apparently shown in _Combinatorial, algebraic and topological representations of groups, semigroups and categories_.

Comment: @ReidBarton let $a(X)$ be the cardinality of the underlying topological space of a scheme $X$ and let $b(X)$ be the cardinality of the disjoint union of the stalks of the structure sheaf of $X$ at all points. The construction in the linked answer satisfies $|F(X)|=a(X)+2^{b(X)}$. Is it possible to find a faithful functor $G$ such that say $|G(X)|\leq a(X)+b(X)$?